# How do I disable to edit PDFAnnotations?

Tags: swift, pdf, pdf-annotations, ios-pdfkit

I'm builting iOS app in Swift 4.2 that can make signature to PDF file.
But in case Embeding the signature as PDFAnnotation, it can editable in apple's Preview app or other app which can edit pdf.
How can I disable to edit PDFAnnoations ??

"Signature" is creates by UIImage which converted handwriting beizerpaths.

```swift
class SignatureAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {

    var image: UIImage!

    init(with image: UIImage!, forBounds bounds: CGRect, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        super.init(bounds: bounds,
                   forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.freeText,
                   withProperties: properties) 
        self.image = image
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        guard let cgImage = self.image.cgImage else { return }
        context.draw(cgImage, in: self.bounds)
    }

}

func embedSignatureToPDF() {
    let page = pdfView.currentPage
    let signatureAnnotation = SignatureAnnotation(with: signature, forBounds: signatureRect, withProperties: nil)
        page.addAnnotation(signatureAnnotation)
}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?  , I noticed this behaviour with my app but I didn't find any solution to fix it

Comment: @Basil Hi Basil. No, still not resolved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution!

The idea here is not using PDFAnnotation!.

the Signature is an Image 
so when user save the PDF

you will use the signature Image
to create new PDF
and save it to same PDF file

to put your signature where you want it
you need the modify **X** and **Y**
`image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))`

the code below will get the Path of the PDF 
usually, it saved in Document Folder 
you just need to send the Path of the file 
and also the signature image
and the function will add the image above the PDF and save it

```
   func drawOnPDF(path: String , signatureImage:UIImage) {

        // Get existing Pdf reference
    let pdf = CGPDFDocument(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))

        // Get page count of pdf, so we can loop through pages and draw them accordingly
    let pageCount = pdf?.numberOfPages


        // Write to file
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(path, CGRect.zero, nil)

        // Write to data
        //var data = NSMutableData()
        //UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil)

        for index in 1...pageCount! {

            let page =  pdf?.page(at: index)

            let pageFrame = page?.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)


            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame!, nil)

            let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            // Draw existing page
            ctx!.saveGState()

            ctx!.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

            ctx!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageFrame!.size.height)
            //CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -pageFrame.size.height);
            ctx!.drawPDFPage(page!)
            ctx!.restoreGState()

            // Draw image on top of page
            let image = signatureImage
            image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
            // Draw red box on top of page
            //UIColor.redColor().set()
            //UIRectFill(CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100));
        }


        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Basil ! I thought that there was only one way to not use PDF Annotation. It will be ok add the signature on which PDF page. That was a really big help

Comment: Glad to be helpful, Could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about change the annotation type to button ?, it will have a overlay everytime you touch the signature but it can't be edited

```
init(with image: UIImage!, forBounds bounds: CGRect, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
    super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget, withProperties: properties)
    self.image = image
    self.isReadOnly = true
    self.widgetFieldType = .button
}
```